# c language bitwise trick

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Here is code i saw in a C program ,  i knew this piece of code is to set  a bit in the bit ASCII bit map corresponding to the character c.

```
field[ (c & 0x7f) >> 3 ] |= 1 << (c & 0x07);
```

field is an array of 16 characters, each character is 8 bits.

for example '97' is lower case 'a', if we set c to 97, then  bit position 97 will be set to 1.

any one know why above code will set bit map corresponding to the character c?
and what are those magic number 0x7f, 0x07, 3 and 1 for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your array is 16 bytes long, it has 128 bits (16 x 8). So the first mask (0x7f) guarantees that you are only interested in the first 128 bits. Once you shift it 3 bits right, you have 4 bits left that are used to address your bitfield (the number ((c & 0x7F) >> 3 is a number between 0 and 15). So this part uses the upper 4 bits to address the byte.

Now, you need to address the bit in the byte, so you use the mask 0x07 to limit the value to the range 0 - 7 (corresponding to the bits 0 to 7). You use this number to shift the 1 so many positions.

At the end, you have a bit set in a position 0 to 127 (16 bytes of 8 bits). I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

First, to clear up the magic numbers

`0x7f` is `0111 1111` in binary. This means the lower 7 bits of c are significant. This is then shifted by 3 so that only the original `0xxx x000` (4) bits are significant. But since these bits are shifted by 3 they count 0 to 15.

`0x07` is `0000 0111` in binary. This means only the lower 3 bits are significant. The number 1 is shifted left by the value in these 3 bits, resulting a bit set in bit positions 0 to 7 within the byte.

In the end, the function only uses the lower 7 bits in the byte, which are the only significant bits in an ascii character. It uses the upper 4 for addressing the byte in the array and the bottom 3 to address the bit in the addressed byte.